# User Profile Service Application Error: "Unable to process Put message "

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When I try to save changes to an existing synchronization connection in the User Profile Service Application in SharePoint 2010 I get the following error:

**"Unable to process Put message".**

In the event log I get three error messages:

**1. Forefront Identity Manager Event ID 3**

```
Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Service: Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ResourceManagementException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at MIISRCW.IMMSManagementAgent.ModifyMAData(String pszMADataXML, String& ppszUpdatedXML)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.SyncConfig.SetMaData(Guid maGuid, String maData)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ActionProcessor.SyncConfigActionProcessor.Update(Guid objectId, CultureInfo locale, IList1 updateParameters, Guid cause)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ActionProcessor.SyncConfigActionProcessor.Update(Guid objectId, CultureInfo locale, IList`1 updateParameters, Guid cause)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ActionProcessor.SyncConfigActionProcessor.ProcessInputRequest(RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ActionProcessor.ActionDispatcher.ProcessInputRequest(RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.ExecuteAction(RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.ExecuteAction[ResponseBodyType](RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest[ResponseBodyType](RequestType request, Guid requestIdentifier, Object redispatchSingleInstanceKey)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest[ResponseBodyType](RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest(RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManagementService.Put(Message request)
```

**2. Forefront Identity Manager Event ID 3**

```
Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ResourceManagementException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at MIISRCW.IMMSManagementAgent.ModifyMAData(String pszMADataXML, String& ppszUpdatedXML)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.SyncConfig.SetMaData(Guid maGuid, String maData)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.ActionProcessor.SyncConfigActionProcessor.Update(Guid objectId, CultureInfo locale, IList`1 updateParameters, Guid cause)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**3. FIMSynchronization Service Event ID 6309**

The server encountered an unexpected error while performing an operation for a management agent.

```
 "BAIL: MMS(6196): mastate.cpp(10154): 0x80040154 (Class not registered)
BAIL: MMS(6196): mastate.cpp(6332): 0x80040154 (Class not registered)
BAIL: MMS(6196): ma.cpp(1334): 0x80040154 (Class not registered)
BAIL: MMS(6196): ma.cpp(1592): 0x80040154 (Class not registered)
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.11"
```

I had this instance of the User Profile Service Application set up and working for several months before this problem popped up.  My guess is it's related to a Cumulative Update or something like that.  Has anyone seen this problem or have any idea how to fix it?  I've already tried everything in this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/8ee7a934-3336-4041-8993-7d55380b244f/.

Thanks in advance,

John P.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens but if you restart these Windows services it should start working

- Forefront Identity Manager Service
- Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service